# Making a button redirect to google

Tags: html, css

If you visit http://bdsfineandrare.co.uk you will see there is a disclaimer, on the decline button. Would anyone be able to assist me in making it so it redirects a user to Google?

I have tried several procedures but it doesn't seem to work. It makes the buttons style disappear with only text visible.

Comment: Post what you have tried so we can help you.

Comment: Just have the decline button link directly to google. What exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place this within the `<h4>` tag:

```
onclick="if(confirm('Disagree to our Terms and Conditions?')){window.location.href='http://www.google.com'};"
```

Answer (score -1):

In general you could do:

```
<html>
    <script>
        function redirect (){
            window.location.assign("http://www.google.com");
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <button onclick="redirect()"> click me </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That’s a really fragile way of making a link.